# Code sandbox and local react behave differently

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to react and I am trying to change the color of the navbar. I modified the property backgroundColor and the color changes in code sandbox.
But when I run the same code on my local machine the color is not changed until I put `!important`.
**Why does it behave differently for the same code ? And how to avoid such discrepencies ?**

Code in local machine-

```
import * as React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  navbar: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
});

export default function Navbar() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static" elevation={0} className={classes.navbar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Output in local machine-
[image: Local machine output]

Sandbox link- https://codesandbox.io/s/buttonappbar-material-demo-forked-8s64r?file=/demo.js:471-472

Comment: If you want to avoid the CSS hammer that is "!important" then you necessarily need to inspect the DOM in both places where the app is rendered and look at the CSS and computed styles to see what is possibly conflicting/overriding the background color locally, and then provide a *more* specific CSS selector.

Comment: Used the CSS hammer and it worked !! But the behavior seems weird. Thanks anyways.